# get data from php simple html dom into json but can't pasre this json in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to create a json data from php simple html dom parser But it almost returns invalid data because I'm trying to parse this json response in ajax request and i get this error in console  "parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 913"

this is my php function that return a invalid json

```
function getUrls($url){
    $responses= array();
    $response2["status"] = 1;
    $responses[] = $response2;
    $fbPost = grab_page($url);
    $postUsers = new simple_html_dom();
    $postUsers->load($fbPost);
    foreach($postUsers->find('#m_story_permalink_view h3 a') as $fbUserDiv) {
        $data = $fbUserDiv->href;
        $userurl['user_url'] = $data;
        $response["data"] = $userurl;
         
    
        $responses[] = $response;
    }
    echo json_encode($responses);

}
```

And this is my json response :

```
[{"status":1},{"data":{"user_url":"\/profile.php?id=100006046927552&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=C-R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"https:\/\/mbasic.facebook.com\/groups\/ultrasfci2\/?refid=18&amp;__tn__=C-R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/profile.php?id=100071323021139&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/ammar.hosny.33?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/rawan.magdy.37017?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/michaelabdo.michaelabdo.9?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/profile.php?id=100022618071315&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/abrar.agour?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/ahmedaymendaana?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/ahmed.abdulrhman.9231712?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/profile.php?id=100024243560746&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}},{"data":{"user_url":"\/abdallh.gmal.393?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"}}]
```

my Java Script code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $("#getUsersId").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "fbReq.php",
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function (response) {

                if(response.status == 1){

                    console.log("success");
                    $.each(response, function(key, value) { 

                        $("#myTextarea").val(value.data.user_url);
     
                    });
            }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });

        });



});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is `obj` defined?

Comment: @Twisty i editi the code now , its the response data of ajax , the ajax success function not work i tried to write somthing in it and didn't work

Comment: The issue is related to your check of `status`. `response` is an array, so to get that call `response[0].status` this way you get the first ekement of the Array, an Object, and then call the element of the Object.

Comment: @Twisty not working because success function not return anything , because i'm using dataType: 'json' when i change it to dataType: 'html' it return the data but can't parse it i get error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

**JavaScript**

```
$("#getUsersId").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "fbReq.php",
    data: new FormData(this),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
      if (response[0].status == 1) {
        console.log("success");
        $.each(response, function(i, val) {
          if(i > 0){
            $("#myTextarea").val(val.data.user_url);
          }
        });
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

This properly addresses a response like:

```
[{
  "status": 1
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/profile.php?id=100006046927552&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=C-R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "https:\/\/mbasic.facebook.com\/groups\/ultrasfci2\/?refid=18&amp;__tn__=C-R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/profile.php?id=100071323021139&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/ammar.hosny.33?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/rawan.magdy.37017?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/michaelabdo.michaelabdo.9?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/profile.php?id=100022618071315&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/abrar.agour?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/ahmedaymendaana?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/ahmed.abdulrhman.9231712?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/profile.php?id=100024243560746&amp;refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "user_url": "\/abdallh.gmal.393?refid=18&amp;__tn__=R"
  }
}]
```

Comment: not working because success function not return anything , because i'm using dataType: 'json' when i change it to dataType: 'html' it return the data but can't parse it i get error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON" .

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMohamed this suggests an issue in your PHP Code. You must not output anything before the JSON and would be best to add Header.

Comment: yes the problem was that I had to print the json twice, once inside if condition where I set $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'  And once outside if condition , i solved it thank you

Answer (score -1):

what output you get.. when you put `console.log(response)`

```
var parsedJson= $.parseJSON(response);
```

or

```
var parsedJson= JSON.parse(response);
if(parsedJson[0].status==1){
}
```

Comment: i didn't get anything ,

Comment: before processing getUrls function.. check if the formData is received or not in fbReq.php

Comment: yes it's received in fbReq.php and i get response in netwok request , I tried more than 5 hours to solve this problem but I didn't get anything :(

Comment: var parsedJson= $.parseJSON(response);

Comment: Not Working it's not return anything ,because i'm using dataType: 'json' when i change it to dataType: 'html' it return data but i want to check if the status is 1 or not